# macd returning incorrect values in R

Tags: r

I'm Using R ,TTR library.
My Algorithm for calculating MACD is :

```
MACD Line: (12-day EMA - 26-day EMA)    
Signal Line: 9-day EMA of MACD Line
```

My R code for MACD Calulation is:

`macd123 = MACD(data[c('Close')],12,26,9,maType=EMA)`

Which is passing me two values `MACD` & `Signal`

Well, this both values are not matching with my Trading Software.
So,I `find 12 and 26 day EMA` using R and then `Subtracted 26 Day EMA from 12 Day EMA to get MACD value.`
But this value is not even matching with macd123(previously calculated MACD).

It will be great if you can correct my code to get the desired output values of MACD and Signal.

Here is my R code:

```
library("TTR")    
data = read.csv(file="F:\\Project_files\\data\\Bambino.csv")    
sma20 <- SMA(data[c('Close')],n=20)    
ema14 <- EMA(data[c('Close')],n=14)    
ema12 <- EMA(data[c('Close')],n=12)    
ema26 <- EMA(data[c('Close')],n=26)    
bb20 = BBands(data[c('Close')],sd=2.0)
rsi14 = RSI(data[c('Close')],n=14)    
macd = MACD(data[c('Close')],12,26,9,maType=EMA)
allData= data.frame(data,sma20,ema14,bb20,rsi14,macd,ema12,ema26)

write.table(allData,file="F:\\Project_files\\temp\\testgejavaedbyR1.csv",na="0.000001",sep=",",row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: please add a small reproducible example with your expected results

Answer (score 2):

You should not expect `ema12 - ema26` to match the output of `MACD`, because `MACD` calculates the percentage difference between the two moving averages by default, as it's documented to do (`percent = TRUE`).

If you want to use the raw difference, set `percent = FALSE` in your `MACD` call. For example:

```
library(TTR)
data(ttrc)
macd <- MACD(ttrc[,"Close"], percent = FALSE)
mymacd <- EMA(ttrc[,"Close"], 12) - EMA(ttrc[,"Close"], 26)
identical(mymacd, macd[,"macd"])  # TRUE
```

Comment: Yes, After Adding `percent = FALSE` ,I'm getting both of them identical. But as I mentioned in a My Question, This MACD and Signal Line are not Correlating with Output of my Trading Software. Do I need to add more Attribute in My code?  `macd = MACD(data[c('Close')],12,26,9,maType=EMA,percent = FALSE)` Thanks

Comment: @KomalBangde: you haven't provided any input or output from your trading software, or any indication of how your trading software actually calculates the MACD values.  Therefore, I can't give you any suggestions about what you should do to make the values match.  The TTR source code is publicly available, so you can see exactly how it calculates its values.